# Verb is and predicate logic

Tags: predicate-logic

I am a bit confused when translating categorical sentences in language of predicate logic. I am trying to be as exacted I can be. That means capital letters for verbs **only**, the rest are individual constants.

Example:

**All Greeks are men** 
maybe could this be translated like this:

∀(x)∀(y)[ARE(x) → ARE(y)] 
where x= Greek, and y = men 
or 
∀(x, y)[ARE(x, y)]

Comment: I would write it as $\forall x (\mathrm{Greek}(x) \to \mathrm{Man}(x))$.

Comment: That is like in a book. Are my above solutions valid?

Comment: No, your solutions are not good. You need to have "Greek" and "Man" inside the formula, not outside. And $ARE(x)$ just says "x is" or, when combined with "$x = \mathrm{Greek}$", "Greek is". Your statement does not say "if $x$ is Greek then $x$ is Man".

Comment: I am confused because in a textbook it is written that capital letter is predicate. Here we have only nouns as predicates.

Comment: The verb "(to) be" is a *copula verb* which means it doesn't describe an activity but is used to connect the subject to something more describing like an adjective (e.g. *Greek* or *male*). Therefore it's more natural to use the adjective as the predicate in the formula. One could also have written $\forall x ( \mathrm{IS}(x, \mathrm{Greek}) \to \mathrm{IS}(x, \mathrm{Male}) )$ but what is the general definition of $\mathrm{IS}$ and what type of mathematical objects are $\mathrm{Greek}$ and $\mathrm{Male}$?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: That makes sense - when you look on IS as copula. I look at is/are as verb of existence. In a sense All Greeks are (that exist) men. Don't know what math. objects they could be.

Comment: It has been truly said that existence is not a predicate.

Comment: @md2perpe How would you wrote: Some footballer wrote a PhD thesis? The solution that I found is   **(∃x)(Fx & (∃y)(Wxy & Ty))**. I would wrote it without **Ty** which represents PhD thesis.

Comment: I would write it as $\exists x \exists y \left( \mathrm{Footballer}(x) \wedge \mathrm{Thesis}(y) \wedge \mathrm{Wrote}(x,y) \right)$.

Comment: @md2perpe what is the correct answer?

Comment: The "is" in the above statement can be equated to "inclusion" (see set theory): the set of *Greeks* is included into (is a subset of) the set of  *Men*: $\text {Greeks} \subseteq \text {Men}$.

Comment: According to the mathematical definition, the above is defined as follows: $\forall x \ (x \in \text {Greeks} \to x \in \text {Men})$.

Comment: We can use instead of names for sets the corersponding *predicates*, to get: $\forall x \ (\text {Greek}(x) \to \text {Man}(x))$.

Comment: This is the correct why to explain where the copula "is" disappeared: first it has been transalted in the relation of (set) *inclusion*, which in turn is defined in terms of the *conditional* connecetive: ($\to$ : "if ..., then ...").

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I think i get it. I was confused how to write that statesmen. Now, I am not sure in what detail I should go in expressing predicates.

Comment: With the predicate expression $\text {Greek}(x)$ we symbolize: "$x$ is Greek", and so on. In set language we have $x \in \text {Greeks}$ where the binary predicate "in" ($\in$) translates the verb *to be*.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA What about Some footballer wrote a PhD thesis? This solution: (∃x)(Fx & (∃y)(Wxy & Ty)) or this one: ∃x∃y(Footballer(x)∧Thesis(y)∧Wrote(x,y)). I am maybe forfirst one although both are valid. I think so.. Right?

Comment: Yes, the two are equivalent, "modulo" using the same symbols.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA that is true although the first solution looks better because explains/has more info.

Comment: In what sense ? they are equivalent, and thus they have the same "info".

Comment: Sorry I tought I defined what kind of thesis that is PhD. Just add & PhD(y) near Thesis(y).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA that is what I meant in what detail should you express sentences